# Even though decimal digit are correct, assert are getting failed

Tags: nunit, assert

I have those 2 values :

```
Expected Value (fResult)= 103393.431493782901937514
Actual Value   (output) = 103393.431493782901937514
```

When I assert on the value, my expected result was consider as `103393.431493783m`

Because of that my Assert was fails. Can anyone help in this regard.

```
Assert.That(output, Is.EqualTo(fResult));
```

More Information: both Actual and Expected values are Decimal data type,

```
[TestCase("value1", "value2", 5, 103393.431493782901937514)]
public void converFormulaforPressure(String Fromunit, String toUnit, decimal Avalue, decimal fResult) {
    var output = ut1.Convert(ut1.GetUnit("Pressure", Fromunit), ut1.GetUnit("Pressure", toUnit), Avalue).Val;

    Assert.That(output, Is.EqualTo(fResult));
}
```

ut1.Convert is a method which converts the value and give the Actual result .

Answer (score 5):

You need to provide a tolerance level **and** you cannot pass a `decimal` as a `TestCase` parameter. The code you provided is passing the last value as a `double`, hence the rounding when you run the assert. You can solve this by using `TestCaseSource` instead.

The test below passes:

```
private static readonly object[] TestCases = {
    new object[] {"value1", "value2", 5m, 103393.431493782901937514m}
};

[Test, TestCaseSource("TestCases")]
public void TestExample(string fromUnit, string toUnit, decimal value, decimal fResult) {
    //Replace the line below with your convert method using values from testCase
    var output = 103393.431493782901937514m;

    Assert.That(output, Is.EqualTo(fResult).Within(0.00000000000001));
}
```

Comment: I have tried tolerance level by using "Within(0.000000001) or Within(0.000000005)", for some Testcases it fails because i have to confirm   14 digits after the decimal should match.

Comment: Then you should increase your tolereance level to 14 digits: `.Within(0.00000000000001)`

Comment: Even though numB have more than 14 decimal digits, VS 2013 takes less number of decimal digits(103393.4314937) in Expected value, and fails the test case